# Ambiguous behaviour of .bss segment in C program

Tags: c, global-variables, size, objdump, object-files

I wrote the simple C program (test.c) below:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

and executed the follwing to understand size changes in .bss segment.

```
gcc test.c -o test
size test
```

The output came out as:-

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1115     552       8    1675     68b test
```

I didn't declare anything globally or of static scope. So please explain why the bss segment size is of 8 bytes.

I made the following change:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int x;    //declared global variable
int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

But to my surprise, the output was same as previous:-

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1115     552       8    1675     68b test
```

Please explain.
I then initialized the global:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int x=67;    //initialized global variable
int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

The data segment size increased as expected, but I didn't expect the size of bss segment to reduce to 4 (on the contrary to 8 when nothing was declared). Please explain.

```
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
1115        556       4    1675     68b test
```

I also tried the comands objdump, and nm, but they too showed variable x occupying .bss (in 2nd case). However, no change in bss size is shown upon size command.

I followed the procedure according to: 
http://codingfox.com/10-7-memory-segments-code-data-bss/
 where the outputs are coming perfectly as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you compile a simple `main` program you are also linking startup code.
This code is responsible, among other things, to init bss.

That code is the code that "uses" 8 bytes you are seeing in .bss section.

You can strip that code using [-nostartfiles](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) gcc option:

> **-nostartfiles**
>
> Do not use the standard system startup files when linking. The standard system libraries are used normally, unless -nostdlib or -nodefaultlibs is used

To make a test use the following code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int _start()
{
   return 0;
}
```

and compile it with

```
gcc -nostartfiles test.c
```

Youll see .bss set to 0

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    206     224       0     430     1ae test
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the same using -nostartfiles flag, but the executable when run giving **Hello world segmentation fault (code dumped)**! How is that? Also, when I compile with **gcc -Wall -nostartfiles 1test.c**, it gives: **/usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000008048230**. Given my program: `#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
 printf("Hello world\n");
 return 0;
}`

Comment: @Ac3_DeXt3R As the warning says: if you remove standard start files with **-nostartfiles** you must provide a `_start` function that will be the entry point of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Your first two snippets are identical since you aren't using the variable `x`.

Try this

```
#include<stdio.h>
volatile int x;
int main()
{
   x = 1;
   return 0;
}
```

and  you should see a change in `.bss` size.

Please note that those 4/8 bytes are something inside the start-up code. What it is and why it varies in size isn't possible to tell without digging into all the details of mentioned start-up code.